# How to open terminal in jupyterlab directly where notebook is present?

Tags: jupyter-lab

When I create a new terminal in JupyterLab, it creates a new terminal at the home folder. Considering that I'm logging in to JupyterLab from outside, and I don't know where my current notebook is present, how can I open the location of the notebook (e.g. "E:\Python") in the new terminal (which defaults to "C:\Users<USERNAME>")?

Comment: there you go : https://shanyitan.medium.com/how-to-change-the-working-directory-of-jupyter-and-jupyter-lab-on-windows-environment-bbe5a5a99f05

Answer (score 1):

You can open two types of terminals from within JupyterLab:

1. **Python terminal**

   - Right click in a notebook and select `New Console for Notebook`.
   - This will open a python terminal at the bottom of the notebook.
2. **System command line terminal**

   - In the toolbar, click `File` -> `New` -> `Terminal`
   - This will open a system terminal as a new tab.

Comment: I think the original asker of the question knows of their options, but wants to know of a way to configure the terminal or settings so that we can easily open up a terminal at a specific location. For example, I'm running jupyter lab on SageMaker AWS. my terminal doesn't show me where I am in the directory so I have to hit 'ls' and 'cd' over and over to get to where I want which is annoying.